# Windows Forms Separator Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Where in VS2010 can I find a horizontal separator control, as can be found in Outlook settings (screenshots below)?

https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/14933/outlook+settings.jpg
http://www.keithfimreite.com/Images/OutlookSettings3.gif

Note: VB.NET preferred, but C# answers okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though this has been answered, I found the following to be what I need based partly on *smoore*'s answer.

Create a new control. Edit the code to be the following:

```
public partial class Line : Label
{
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override Size MaximumSize
    {
        get
        {
            return new Size(int.MaxValue, 2);
        }
    }

    public override Size MinimumSize
    {
        get
        {
            return new Size(1, 2);
        }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public Line()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Height = 2;
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
}
```

Replace **Line** with the control's class name you want. This will put a separator that will allow you to resize in the designer and disables adding text, changing the autosize forces the size's height to be 2 and width to be whatever you want, and disables adding text.

Answer (score 20):

If I'm not mistaken, that's just a Line control, but I don't think that control exists anymore.  [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/separator-line/) is a workaround.

```
label1.AutoSize = False
label1.Height = 2
label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not actually included in the standard set of controls (pretty sure it used to be back in the day!) but you can easily create your own or cheat by using a GroupBox with no text and a height of 1px.

UserControl to provide the same thing: (Not written by me, source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/0d4b986e-3ed0-4933-a15d-4b42e02005a7/)

```
public partial class LineSeparator:UserControl
{

    public LineSeparator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(LineSeparator_Paint);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(2000, 2);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 2);
        this.Width = 350;
    }

    private void LineSeparator_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, new Point(0, 0), new Point(this.Width, 0));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.White, new Point(0, 1), new Point(this.Width, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes you wonder why the limit of 2000, that's not even enough to cover a 2-screen setup. Reminds me of Solomon's shoddy programming.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom control just for this purpose. It supports both vertical and horizontal modes. Just install my [small] control suite and drag the separator control onto the form and place it anywhere you want.

```
Install-Package ALMSTWKND -Version 1.0.0
```

The controls will show up in the Toolbox pane after installation.