# C# Drop Down menu with labels in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to have a drop down menu in Winforms in C# with Text Label in between the menu items. It will be very similar to seperators. So basically I am looking at an option of grouping the menu items.

Any idea how we can achieve it ? Attached is the drop-down menu I wish to have.
[image]

Comment: You can easily create your own label control and get it added to the designer selections.  Getting it to extend into the image gutter is however going to be difficult.

Comment: I just want to mention that my solution does that

Comment: Did my suggestion worked for you Kiran?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using VS2010

In the Menu Designer, right-click the location where you want a separator bar, and choose Convert To -> Separator.

[image]

[MSDN Article on menu enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983550%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You might want take a look at this also (Its about **form** separators, but version is VS2003!) -- [Windows Forms Separator Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022137/windows-forms-separator-control)

Answer (score 0):

May be below link can help you:

[A Seperator Combo List Vox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18971/A-Separator-Combo-List-Box)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many complex ways to do this but i've found one that might satisfy your needs in 3 Steps:

1.You make your own ToolStripItem:

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
public sealed class CustomToolStripMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem
{

    public CustomToolStripMenuItem()
    {
        DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
        BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        ForeColor = Color.MidnightBlue;
        Font = new Font(Font, FontStyle.Bold);
       // Or other options to your liking
     }
}
```

2.You make your own Renderer:

```
public class CustomeRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{

    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item is CustomToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSteelBlue, e.Item.ContentRectangle);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        }
    }
}
```

3.Use your items:
For your contextmenu you need to set up the renderer:

```
 RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional;
 Renderer = new CustomeRenderer();
```

In your context menu you can now use your CustomToolStripMenuItem